# Ruby on Rails Form For with two parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code but I am not able to understand hows does routing happen for form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]).

**Title:**
          <%= @article.title %>

```
    <p>
      <strong>Text:</strong>
      <%= @article.text %>
    </p>

    <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
    <%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :body %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :body %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
    | <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails can imply the route from the form_for

e.g.

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

If @article is new and not in the database, then rails can deduce you are creating a new one, then the route would be

```
articles_path(@article), action: :create
```

If @article already exists in the database then rails can deduce you are editing an existing object, so the path is.

```
article_path(@article), action: :update
```

This applies to nested routes as well like the example code you have.

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

It know the parent route is article and the sub route is comments, since it is a new comment, the route would be

```
article_comments_path(@article, @article.comments.build), action: :create
```

If comment exists then it will be an update action

```
article_comment_path(@article, @comment), action: :update
```

Any form_for, link_to, etc can imply the path from the objects.

Answer (score 2):

To do that you would have to have your comments routs nested under your article. So your rout file would have something like this

```
resources :article
  resources :comments
end
```

This creates several routes, the one this form would go it is

```
POST  /posts/:post_id/comments
```

And in the form_for helper `form_for([@article, @article.comments.build])` tells the form to post to that rout